# Cannot record screen with headless Chrome and FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, google-chrome-headless

Before I used Xvfb to render Chrome, use selenium do button clicks and use FFmpeg to capture it with `-f x11grab`.

Now I want to use headless Chrome to render my target site. I found I cannot record the screen as before. It seems FFmpeg doesn't support it yet.

I have tried an idea like generate lots of screenshots and pipe to FFmpeg `-f image2pipe`, but it looks bit weird. I'm looking for more "native" way to do that.

What's the correct way in do that? Or do I need to go back to Xvfb solution?

Comment: What version of ffmpeg are u using? Recently ffmpeg has deprecated x11grab support and replaced it with xcbgrab.

Comment: @halfelf i checked the latest FFmpeg doc here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop, it still recommend to use x11grab.